# Javascript object result has additional character

Tags: javascript, object

This question might be ridiculous but I tried searching everywhere but I just can't find a good reference.

Why does some object in javascript has the structure like in the image attached below?
[image]

There is `t` character. And how do I convert the normal object to that form? For instance:

```
{
    key: "training",
    amount: 4500,
    currency: "PLN",
    label: "Training",
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the t is there but you are not closing the `key`. Try adding `"` at the end of `"training`

Comment: The `t` is probably the class that created the Object.

Comment: @VinitS My bad, it's just a typo in my question but thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Are you sure that's the same object? The properties in the image don't match the ones in the object. Adding a [mcve] to the question would help us debug it.

Comment: @Andy No it's different I'm trying to produce the same object result by using the object that I have because the platform that I use cannot accept the normal object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character `t` is the class name of the object that is passed as the value of the key `value`. As user @Vishnudev mentioned in the comments.

Consider the following code to recreate the JavaScript object and its structure in the image.

#### Code

```js
class t{
  constructor( amount, currency, _sdkType) { 
    this.amount = amount
    this.currency = currency
    this._sdkType = _sdkType
  }
}
let value = new t(4500, "PLN", "Money")
let object = {
  value: value
}

console.log(object)
```

#### Output

Result as seen in the browser console.

[image]